# How to hide the value in table and anchor tag when user click the anchor return

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to hide the row when the admin click the anchor return because It's already saved in return.php so just need hide the returned status while the pending is not. Thank you for helping me

```
  <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Book title</th>                                 
                                    <th>Borrower</th>                                 
                                    <th>Type</th>                                 
                                    <th>Date Borrow</th>                                 
                                    <th>Due Date</th>                            
                                    <th>Date Returned</th>
                                    <th>Fines</th>
                                    <th>Borrow Status</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                              <?php  $user_query=mysqli_query($dbcon,"select * from borrow
                            LEFT JOIN member ON borrow.member_id = member.member_id
                            LEFT JOIN borrowdetails ON borrow.borrow_id = borrowdetails.borrow_id
                            LEFT JOIN book on borrowdetails.book_id =  book.book_id 
                            ORDER BY borrow.borrow_id DESC
                              ")or die(mysqli_error());
                                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($user_query)){


$currentdate = date('Y/m/d');

$start = new DateTime($returndate=$row['due_date']); 

$end = new DateTime($currentdate);  

$fines =0;

if(strtotime($currentdate) > strtotime($returndate)){


 $days= $start->diff($end, true)->days;
$fines = $days > 0 ? intval(floor($days)) * 10 : 0;
$fi = $row['borrow_details_id'];
mysqli_query($dbcon,"update borrowdetails set fines='$fines' where borrow_details_id = '$fi'");
}

                                $id=$row['borrow_id'];
                                $book_id=$row['book_id'];
                                $borrow_details_id=$row['borrow_details_id'];

                                    ?>
                                <tr class="del<?php echo $id ?>">


                                <td><?php echo $row['book_title']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['date_borrow']; ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo $row['due_date']; ?> </td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['date_return']; ?> </td>
                                 <td><?php echo "₱ ".$fines; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['borrow_status'];?></td>
                                <td> <a rel="tooltip"  title="Return" id="<?php echo $borrow_details_id; ?>"
                                 href="#delete_book<?php echo $borrow_details_id; ?>" data-toggle="modal"   
                                  class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-check icon-large"></i>Return</a>
                                <?php include('modal_return.php'); ?>
                                <td></td> 

                                </tr>
                                <?php  }  ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

This is the view_return.php where will admin see the all books pending
[image: Returning Book]

This is the history/transaction where the book is already return
[image: History of Return book]

Answer (score 0):

For this , you can do like below example, Add a class "test" in anchorTag or in td 
and by using jquery

---

```js
$('.test').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().hide();
        });
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td class="test" id="returnId1">Return</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Test2</td>
    <td class="test" id="returnId2">Return</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: not working bro and the modal didn't show up after click return :(

Comment: Are u include jquery plugin file in your php file ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/oq4st , https://imgur.com/a/5CazW I already did that :(

Comment: can you put  my jquery code in -  $(document).ready(function(){ --put here--  });